# Datapower to tomcat - (Unexpected number of X509Data: for decryption (KeyId))

Tags: encryption, certificate

```
We are facing below error in tomcat.(response sent from datapower)
Datapower < ---- Tomcat (successfull)
Datapower ---- > Tomcat (failing with below error)
Someone please guide what can be the reason?
```

**Error log**

The Encrypted XML is :
    [#document: null]
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: **General security error (Unexpected number of X509Data: for decryption (KeyId))**
      at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:184)
      at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:87)
      at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleToken(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:76)
      at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:279)
      at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:201)
      at com.net.hold.WSSecUtil.SignAndEncryptEnvelope.decryptAndVerify(SignAndEncryptEnvelope.java:254)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.basicutility.ProducerServiceUtil.ProducerServiceCrypter.decrypt(ProducerServiceCrypter.java:83)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.basicutility.ProducerServiceUtil.ProducerServiceInterface.getProducer(ProducerServiceInterface.java:66)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.ces.cache.RequestLevelInterfaceCache.getProducer(RequestLevelInterfaceCache.java:49)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.ces.customopr.ProducerNumberValidator.execute(ProducerNumberValidator.java:60)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.util.CustomOperationExecutor.executePreOperation(CustomOperationExecutor.java:61)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.model.Rule.execute(Rule.java:86)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.model.Method.executeEditsForARecord(Method.java:259)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.model.Method.executeEditsForEachRecords(Method.java:171)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.model.Method.execute(Method.java:134)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.rulefw.model.MethodGroup.execute(MethodGroup.java:72)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.ces.CESWebServiceHandler.executeAllCorpEdits(CESWebServiceHandler.java:130)
      at com.us.chartisinsurance.corporateeditsv1.CorporateEditServiceV1Impl.validateAllCorporateEdits(CorporateEditServiceV1Impl.java:40)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.util.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:82)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.util.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:107)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:64)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.run(Fiber.java:813)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.start(Fiber.java:420)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.processAsync(WSEndpointImpl.java:368)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:398)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.invokeAsync(HttpAdapter.java:734)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:212)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
      at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. By changing the algorithm type into SHA256RSA